# ASA Slow IPSec Performance with Inconsistent Window Size

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec

I have a IPSec link between two sites over ASA 5520s running 8.4(3) and I am getting extremely poor performance when traffic passes over the IPSec VPN. CPU on the devices is ~13%, Memory at 408 MB, and active VPN sessions 2. The load on both of the the devices is particularly low. Latency between the two sites is ~40ms.

Screenshot of wireshark file transfer between the two hosts over the firewall IPSec VPN performing at 10MBPS. Note the changing window size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsJqG.jpg

Screenshot of wireshark file transfer between the two hosts over the firewall not going over IPSec performing at 55MBPS. Constant window size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoBQN.jpg

I'm showing an inconsistent window size when transferring over the IPSec VPN ranging in 46,796 to 65535. When performing at 55+MBPS, the window size is consistently 65,535. Does this show a problem in my configuration of the IPSec VPN in the ASA or a Layer1/2 issue?

Using ping xxxxxx -f -l I finally get a non-fragment at 1418 bytes so 1418+28 for IP/ICMP headers = 1446. I know that I have 1500 set on the ASA and Ethernet.

I do have "Force Maximum segment size for TCP proxy connection to be" "1380" bytes set under Configuration > Advanced > TCP Options on the ASA.

Using IPERF, I am getting a "TCP Window Full" every few seconds and ~3 MBPS performance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRbkE.jpg

Show Run on the ASA

http://pastebin.com/uKM4Jh76

Show cry accelerator stats

http://pastebin.com/xQahnqK3

Comment: Are all your licensed features within the limits?

Comment: I'm showing License: VPN Plus, Encryption: 3DES/AES, VLANs: 150, Failover: Active/Active, Security Contexts: 4, GTP/GPRS: Disabled, Physical Interfaces: Unlimited, VPN Peers: 750, SSL VPN Peers: 50

Comment: Well, I think the 0x0000 checksums are not related to your problem. The checksum may be caused by the checksum offload (exactly like wireshark says).

Comment: Little followup: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Offloading

Comment: I correct the Windows hosts by disabling offloading. I've also found that the window size is different over the WAN vs LAN. I updated the issue.

Comment: Even though your MTU on the ASA interfaces may be 1500, you have to account for the overhead of the ipsec encapsulation. I beleive the default tunneled traffic mtu is 1380 for ASA. The length of the packets in your log appear to be following this MTU.

Comment: See what the command crypto ipsec df-bit clear-df outside does for you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any luck on resolving this @Brent?

Comment: If I set the Window size to 15MB I get very good bandwith